# Steps to use SNDlib network instances in omnet++ simulator

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I'm trying to repeat the simulation of [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8553652). According to the numerical results section I should  use [SNDlib](http://sndlib.zib.de/) network instances in [omnet++](https://omnetpp.org/). I couldn't find any guide or example on how to use the xml or native files (.txt files) from sndlib in omnet++, build and run the simulation. The only files exist on SNDlib website are some xml(txt) files.

The steps I took are to download and install the omnet++ and download the sndlib files. I tried to import the xml file but I couldn't. Also it seems that the structure of xml files in sndlib are different from the omnet++ (According to documnets). I would appreciate any step by step guide with as much details as possible on how can I run the simulation for SNDlib network instances? Or even if I should convert the xml files from SNDlib to approriate NED files please let me know. If I can use any other simulator simpler than omnet++ for the article simulation please let me know.